# how to display record not found php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

Im using this form that ask the user for their names, and the bottom the query to select their information from the database, but if the name is not found in the database how can alert the user it is possible to include this in `catch(PDOException)` saying `"Error name not found in database"` or something like that

```
 if(!empty($_POST))
{
require ("connection.php");
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$query = "SELECT nombre, ape FROM estudiantes WHERE nombre = '$nombre' ";
  try
  {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
  catch(PDOException $ex)
  {
    die("Error" . $ex->getMessage());
  }
  $rownombres = $stmt->fetchAll();
  <table width="97%" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <th align="left">nombre</th>
      <th align="left">apellido</th> 
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($rowstudent as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo ' ' . htmlentities($row['nombre'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' ';?></td>
      <th><?php echo ' ' . htmlentities($row['ape'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ' ';?></th> 
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
  }

  else 
  {
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="nombre" value="" placeholder="Nombre" />
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
}
```

With a name that is not on the database only display the table headers

Comment: Hi, I found this `"` on the floor here, which I think belongs in your code. It might be important... Do you want it back? :)

Comment: Where are you assigning the post variable? I.e.: `$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];`

Comment: When in development, add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so, and replacing `$pdo` with your PDO connection variable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry i forget to include in the question

Comment: It seems like you've changed your question a bit. I thought you were having problems with your DB showing as "user not found" when querying. This is an entirely different thing. See the answer already given below.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should pass `$nombre` as a parameter to the prepared statement instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you use `die` which is the same as `exit` which will make the PHP stop execution. At that point, whatever is sent to the user is what they will see.

You can either put more detail into the output like this:

```
die("The something was not found in the database...<br>Error" . $ex->getMessage());
```

Or better yet, pop the error into a variable, keep executing the code and then use that error message so that the remainder of your code executes as expected:

```
$errMessage="Error" . $ex->getMessage();
// etc etc and error checking is done on the rest of the page.
```

Edit: Based on comment trail:

```
$rownombres = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Check to see how many records there are here. If there are none, then use that to identify that the user was not found.

```
$rownombres = $stmt->fetchAll();
if(!count($rownombres))
{
    $errMessage="That user was not found in the database.";
}

//// somewhere down the page...

if(!empty($errMessage))
{
    echo $errMessage;
}
```

Comment: but how can I display the message, because this is how it is now and don;t see the message

Comment: Ermm... Get rid of the `die`, save the error into a variable as my answer shows and then echo it out where you want to display it?

Comment: when I click submit, only refreshes the page without any message and if i put a name that is on the database I can the information

Comment: this is the error that i gt if i get rid of die: notice: Undefined variable: errMessage

Comment: Then you need to use an `isset` around your code I.e.: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` and naming your submit button. Without seeing your full PHP, I think that is what's going on. Or, `if(!empty($_POST['nombre'])){...}`

Comment: And the connection to the db is working properly? As in, when you have proper input, it displays the name as expected?

Comment: @Fluffeh yes if I enter a name that is in the database works fine, I update my question with the full code of index.php

Comment: Okay, have a look at the edit I made. Simply check how many records you get from the search results. If it is zero, add in an error message and use it later.